# CoreBluetooth: Is it possible to restore peirpherals after app reinstall

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-location, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I am sure this question looks silly. But I am forced to ask. I am really wondering if the CBCentralManager object which is created using CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey key can be retrieved even after app uninstall and reinstall. I can store the known peripheral ids(which will never change in my case) in my server and get them back upon app reinstall. But what about the CBCentralManager object which is needed to reconnect to known peripheral id's.

Comment: I doubt that your app would be relaunched with for state restoration after being uninstalled. Bluetooth state restoration only occurs when ios relaunched  in the background after detection of a bluetooth event when your app has been terminated by iOS. You could try `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers` but I am not sure if  that would work after an app uninstall/reinstall. It is not up to you to determine whether the identifiers change; the identifier is created by iOS and will vary from device to device, for example

Comment: Hi Paul, It is obvious that a deleted app can't be relaunched by state restoration. What I wanted to check is whether it is possible to obtain the same CBCentralManager object post reinstall with the same CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey passed.

Comment: The state is only restored when you supply a restoration key during your `CBCentralManager` initialisation **and** `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsBluetoothCentralsKey` is passed in the launch options passed to `didFinishLaunching`. Obviously the second condition cannot be satisfied when your application has been reinstalled.

Comment: However, restoring the central manager state is not required for the situation you are describing. [`retrievePeripherals`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1519127-retrieveperipherals) can be used by any central instance to retrieve a peripheral that is known to the device.  Note that this method may not be able to retrieve the peripheral and you will need to fall back to discovery in that case.

Comment: Oh. I was in an assumption that retrievePeripherals can be used by the same central instance only. I will try this and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Paul, I am able to use a new central instance for retrieving previously connected peripherals. Needless to say that blue tooth must be turned on at the time when the method is getting called. Thanks!